# Powerset with upper and lower limits

Tags: c#, linq

I have a process where I need to find all of the best combinations that fit a certain criteria.  Powersets are what I think I am looking for, but i'd like to build in some filters in to avoid millions of results.

For example I have the following Object:

```
public class CableReel
    {
        public string ReelId { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
    }
```

I'd like to get a powerset of the above object where the combined lengths meet a lower limit and also an upper limit as well.

The following list:

"a", 5200
"b", 2500
"c", 1000

I'd like to put in the following limits, min 3000, max 5000.  I'd like to then only see the BC combination.

I have found the following code for returning generic powersets:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
               select
                 from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                 where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                 select list[i];
    }
```

I was just wondering how this might be adapted to accomplish what I am looking to do?

Solution:

Using Alex Sikilinda's advice I came up with:

```
var ls = new List<CableReel>
            {
                new CableReel{Length = 5,ReelId = "A"},
                new CableReel{Length = 3,ReelId = "B"},
                new CableReel{Length = 2,ReelId = "C"},
                new CableReel{Length = 7,ReelId = "e"},
                new CableReel{Length = 3,ReelId = "f"},
                new CableReel{Length = 2,ReelId = "g"}

            };
    var p = GetPowerSet(ls).Where(psl => psl.Sum(ps => ps.Length) > 5 && psl.Sum(ps => ps.Length) < 8);
```

Comment: with limit max limit equals to 5000, how can you get A in the result (A = 5200)?

Comment: @AlexSikilinda I am looking to filter the powerset, not the initial list.

Comment: Which criteria do you want to use to compare powersets with limits? Why AB is a good one (although sum of A + B = 5200 + 2500 = 7700 is greater thean max = 5000)? How do you calculate this critera?

Comment: I see what you mean and I have fixed my question.  With filters between 3000 and 5000, I'd like to see the CB combo because that is the only one that is between those numbers.

Comment: Can you only combine two? Or is any n-way combination acceptable?  For example if max was 10000, would you want to see ABC?

Comment: @RobertMcKee Yes, in a very large powerset I'd like to filter out every combination that falls outside the limits.  

What I am trying to do is to avoid having millions of useless combinations when the only ones I care about are the relatively fewer ones that i'd like within my limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your powerset code works fine, you can just filter the list before calling your method:

```
var filteredList = list.Where(e => e > 4000 || e < 5000);
var result = GetPowerSet(filteredList.ToList());
```

Edited:
because you want to filter not elements, but sets, you can filter the result.
This code demonstrates how you can filters sets, sum of which are bigger than 2:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list,       Func<IEnumerable<T>, Boolean> filter)
    {
        var fullPowerSet = from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
                     select
                       from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                       where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                       select list[i];

        return fullPowerSet.Where(e => filter(e));
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Int32> inputList = new List<Int32>()
        {
            1,2
        };

        var result = GetPowerSet(inputList, ps => ps.Sum() > 1);
    }
```

Now you can change the delegate `ps => ps.Sum() > 1` to get what you want.

Comment: Ah, that's not exactly what I am looking for, I am looking for I am looking to get the limit of the combinations.  So with those three, i'd like to have the combinations that fall within the limits.

Comment: I'd like it to work with the object but I cant seem to get this to work:

var ls = new List<CableReel>
            {
                new CableReel{Length = 5,ReelId = "A"},
                new CableReel{Length = 3,ReelId = "B"},
                new CableReel{Length = 2,ReelId = "C"}
            
            };
            var p = GetPowerSet(ls, ps=> ps.Length.Sum() >= 6);

Comment: I figured it out with:  GetPowerSet(ls).Where(psl => psl.Sum(ps => ps.Length) > 5 && psl.Sum(ps => ps.Length) < 8);